# Stop nesting data of the active model serializer gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I am using the active model serializer gem, and it works fine for now. I have however stumbled upon an issue, where I wan't to stop the nesting of the data retrieved.

Lets say I have 3 models:

`Users` who `has_many orders` who `has_many addresses`.

Normally in my `Users serializer class` I would have have a `has_many` to the `orders model`, and in the orders model serializer have a `has_many` relationship to the `addresses`.

I now have a users controller, where I don't want the orders out, but not the nested addresses. Can this be done without creating a whole new serializer class?

**Update, to clarify:**

I have the following 3 models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many orders 
end

class Orders < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to user
  has_many addresses
end

class Addresses < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to order
end
```

I have 3 serializers which are identical to the models.

For my orders API I would like to retrieve the addresses as well, but when I query users I only wants the associated orders and not addresses. As it is now when I query the users it both returns all the orders and addresses, since I have a has_many to addresses from the orders.

Is the only option to create separate serializers for the two options (it just doesn't feel very DRY)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? You wrote `I now have a users controller, where I don't want the orders out, but not the nested addresses. Can this be done without creating a whole new serializer class?` which isn't exactly clear.

Comment: I used to do that and my solution may apply to you. Please paste example of your code so I can post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [default_serializer_options](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-9-stable#4-define-default_serializer_options-in-your-controller) method that defines serializer options for 
 all serializers and their children used by this controller.

```
#users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def default_serializer_options
    { include_addresses: false }
  end
end
```

Then override initialize method in Order serializers to check **serializer options** for **include_addresses** flag:

```
# order_serializer.rb
class OrderSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  def initialize(object, options = {})
    options.reverse_merge! include_addresses: true # by default it should include addresses
    @include_addresses = options[:include_addresses]
    super
  end

  def include_addresses?
    @include_addresses
  end
end
```

And that's it. Specify this option in every controller that you don't need addresses to be nested.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `has_many` from the serializer and it will stop including the associations.

Comment: I am sorry the question wasn't very precise. I wants to have the has_many for addresses for when querying orders, for which I want the addresses returned.